# Modification of a 3 phase AC motor

Tags: motor, three-phase, magnetic-flux, synchronous-motor

There is a permanent-magnet synchronous motor with an external rotor that I want to explore and possibly modify. To do this I need some answers to my simple question:

For a given shape of stator lamination (in my case a 24 "teeth" one), what is the effect of increasing the length of the stator lamination stack (and larger magnets in the rotor accordingly)?

Comment: The question is tagged "induction motor," but the phrase "magnets in the rotor" implies that this is a permanent-magnet synchronous motor. The rotor length needs to match the stack length of the stator. Is this really a motor modification or a new motor constructed using some salvaged parts? Someone has voted to close the question. That may be because it is not clear. Please edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: I have taken out the "induction" tag if it's so misleading. It is a 3phase AC motor with an external rotor that has a ring magnet firmly attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the stator stack length is increased, the windings are changed to accommodate additional current required for the torque increase, and the number of rotor magnets are also increased to maintain the flux density, the torque capability will be increased in proportion to the increase in length. The length of the rotor body must match the length of the stator stack such that the flux in the air gap is uniform and full use is made of the rotor and stator iron.

Additional rotor weight and torque will put additional stress on the shaft and bearings, but a small motor may have enough safety factor to accommodate that. Given that the motor has an external rotor, the shaft and bearing design might be questionable.

Comment: Thank you! That is really helpful! So is it safe to say that if the parameters you have pointed out are met (length of ring magnet is increased accordingly), then an identical motor with X1.5 or X2 core length will have X1.5 or X2 torque with regards to the original?

Comment: Yes. The electromagnetic design will allow X1.5 or 2 torque. I neglected to mention the mechanical design. There could be a problem with the shaft and bearings. In a small motor, I would expect that there would be a large safety factor, but the safety factor would be reduced accordingly. I did mention the current. It will increase X1.5 or X2, but I didn't state that correctly; see revision.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am going to use a longer shaft cartridge with longer self lubricated bushings. Next question:the copper wire needed for this type of modification will have to be thicker (currently 0.3mm diam) or it can be kept the same? The goal is not to make a faster spinning motor but one with more torque at same (very low) RPM.

Comment: The current drawn will be directly proportional to torque, so X1.5 or 2. The cross sectional area of the wire needs to be increased by that amount.

Comment: I see. But isn't this (thicker wire) going to reduce the number of turns that can be wound on the stator slots? Less turns won't have an effect on the characteristics of the motor?

Comment: It is likely that will be a limitation. I believe that fewer turns will mean that you will need to use a lower voltage and operate at a lower speed.

Comment: The motor is a 3 phase AC motor used to spin the platter of a vinyl turntable in a direct drive scheme. So RPM is pretty low at 33/45/78. I am trying to redesign it so it can be used with a heavier platter...hence the questions. Something else that i would like to ask regarding the magnetic poles on the rotor... For a given 3 phase motor with 24 slots on the core is there a pre-determined number of magnetic poles that can be used? Is there a rule for calculating this number? Eg, does it have to be 6 or 12 or a multiple AND how is this number effecting the smoothness (less cogging)of rotation?

Comment: This question has evolved into a discussion that probably doesn't fit the format and guidelines for this site. Even if it did, I don't think I have the background and resource material to provide the answers that you are looking for.